# Flipped a circuit breaker, now my microwave is dead

Tags: circuit-breaker, microwave-oven

I recently moved into a condo with a GE JVM1860SF001 microwave oven installed above the range. The unit is from 2003, so well past its rated life, although it also looks like it was largely unused (there is no wear on the keypad). Anyway, it was working when I moved in.

Then my daughter flipped a circuit breaker and it went completely dead (kids!). The microwave is fully dead -- the display is off, buttons unresponsive, etc. It's as though it is entirely unplugged.

I have tested the power outlet it is plugged into and it is working fine. My first thought was that an internal fuse was blown, but I tested both of the fuses with a multimeter, and both appear to be fine:

[image: Fuses]

I also tested the thermoprotector with a multimeter. It also seems to be fine.

[image: Thermoprotector]

Any idea what else might be going on here? Could it be the circuit board?

I'm assuming this means it's time for a new microwave...

Comment: Did you actually plug a load into the socket and power something, or did you just check if the hot wire was hot?  Also the child flip the circuit breaker... by operating the breaker handle? Or by causing an overload trip by running a second appliance on the microwave circuit?

Comment: I plugged a load into the outlet. I also tried plugging the microwave into several different outlets that are working. Nothing helped. My kid flipped the breaker by opening up the breaker box and flipping a bunch of switches.

Comment: Were you using the microwave(cooking,heating) when the breaker was flipped?  Do think it is two things happening close in time, instead one causing the other.

Comment: Why did the kid open the service panel and flip the switches? Was it because the microwave oven suddenly stopped working?

Comment: Turning the breaker off should not have caused any problems, it’s less likely to do damage than the normal power bumps that hit most areas regularly. I know I had 1 microwave that when the power went out for more than a few minutes it would not work until the clock was set, I don’t remember the brand but you might try setting the clock. The one I had acted dead until the day , month, year & time was set. I used 1,1,1 for the date as I thought that was ridiculous to keep it from working so it’s worth a try.

Comment: The microwave is "dead". Is the control display active, but it just won't run? Or is the display dead?

Comment: test the DC power going into the controller. if the caps dried out over the last 20 years, the initial surge current from power-up could zap it. Since that would be the first power-up in a while, that makes sense. If the DC power supply is dead, it can easily be replaced with another supply with suitable specs or a direct replacement if you can find one. You might also check all the safety switch contacts for continuity...

Comment: The microwave is fully dead -- the display is off, buttons unresponsive, etc. It's as though it is entirely unplugged.

Comment: I'm not totally sure where to stick the multimeter to check the DC power supply. I tried measuring voltage across some contacts that seem to be supplying power to the controller and I couldn't get a reading.

Comment: the DC supply will be somewhere between the AC fuse and the control panel. Follow the incoming with a continuity beeper until you get to a PCB with a transformer about the size of an acorn to a golf ball. Right around there is the DC supply, probably a small SMPS that feeds the MCU and human interface panel. Sometimes the SMPS and controller are all on one board and you're SOL without major hacking, but often they are semi-modular and a wall wart or two can be crammed into box and wired equivalent to the orig DC supply. As long as the voltages match and current is >=, it should work fine.